# Whether variables should be declared within functions or outside functions?

Tags: c#, .net

Which is good practice:-
Whether variables should be declared within function or outside functions?

.1.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoadData();
            }

            private void LoadData()
            {

**private SqlDataAdapter da;
            private SqlConnection conn;
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            DataSet ds = null;
            string sql;**

    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;";
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sql = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, Freight," + "ShipName, ShipCountry FROM Orders";

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                ds = new DataSet();
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);          
                da.Fill(ds, "Orders");
                bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["Orders"];
                dgv.DataSource = bsource;          
            }
        }
```

.2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            **private SqlDataAdapter da;
            private SqlConnection conn;
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            DataSet ds = null;
            string sql;**

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoadData();
            }

            private void LoadData()
            {
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;";
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sql = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, Freight," + "ShipName, ShipCountry FROM Orders";

                da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                ds = new DataSet();
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);          
                da.Fill(ds, "Orders");
                bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["Orders"];
                dgv.DataSource = bsource;          
            }
        }
```

Comment: Declare a variable in a scope where you need to acess it. If you don't need it outside of a method don't declare it as field but as local variable. On that way you simplify the code and prevent nasty bugs.

Comment: @TimSchmelter make this an answer ;)

Comment: the second one is was better (but still why is `conn` still a field?) - and of course: you should dispose thinks like Connections as soon as you are finished with them! (Basically: everything that has is `IDisposable` should be wrapped inside a `using` block or if it is a field then the class should implement `IDisposable` too and make sure the field is cleaned up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a variable in a scope where you need to acess it. If you don't need it outside of a method don't declare it as field but as local variable. On that way you simplify the code and prevent nasty bugs.

In this case i would use local variables. For another reason specific to the the type of the variable. You should  close a connection as soon as you're finished with it. Otherwise the connection-pool (enabled by default) assumes that it is still in use. Therefore it will open another physical connection instead of reusing the same which will decrease performance and sometime cause exceptions.

You can ensure that a connection gets disposed/closed even on error by using the `using`-statement:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sql = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, Freight," + "ShipName, ShipCountry FROM Orders";
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
    {
        // if you use DataAdapter.Fill you don't need to open the connection 
        da.Fill(ds, "Orders");
        // ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: I would refactor the constant strings into .... *const string* on the class level ;) (ok, the `connectionString` should maybe be an dependency and the value should be stored in the app.settings but that is another topic :D)

Comment: @CarstenKönig: or he could use a  config-file which is also cached. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in the innest scope possible, so Garbage Collector can get rid of it as soon as it is no longer needed.

Comment: this is not about the GC - if the objects are bound somehow inside the methods they won't be GC'ed either

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two ways to declare variables is the way you are going to use them.
In your LoadData function, you're declaring the sql string and use it right after in the SqlDataAdapter, then the declaration should be made in the function, because you're using it to 'punctually' call a method right after.
If you want to be able to read, modify or get the value for a certain variable, but outside of you function, then you should declare it as soon as you write the class. 
TLDR : It all depends on if you use the variable only in a certain function, or if you want it to be accessible by a lot of methods that might want to manipulate this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should always choose the most restrictive, yet possible approach, and this refers not just to variables, but almost everything: fields, properties, methods, class visibilities etc.. By doing so, you are minimizing chances to mess up (accidently using variables, fields, methods you did not intend to use at this point). If you see that the scope is to narrow, you can almost always expand it easily, the other way around can cause a hard time instead...